# How to make unknown width inline-block element stay in the center position after hover

Tags: css, css-position, inline, centering

Here is what I have
A navigation menu with unknown width which I try to center it.
The problem is on hover state the width of this navigation expands so the rule doesn't apply anymore.  (because the width goes above its container width)

```css
  #centerContent {
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto auto;
    padding: 110px 30px 30px 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    }
        #mainNav {
        display: inline-block;
     height: 42px;
     background-color: #f5f5f5;
        white-space: nowrap;
        outline: 1px solid blue;
    }
    
    #mainNav a {
     transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    #mainNav a > * {
     transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    #mainNav > a {
     display: inline-block;
     height: 100%;
     position: relative;
     font: 13px/42px "IranYekanWebLight";
     font-weight: 700;
     color: #575757;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #mainNav > a:hover {
     background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    #mainNav > a:hover span {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 17px;
     padding-right: 75px;
    }
    
    #mainNav > a:hover svg {
     left: 40%;
     fill: #fff;
     animation: 0.3s 1 mainNavAnim;
     animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    
    #mainNav span {
     padding: 0 28px;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
    }
    
    #mainNav svg {
     height: 90px;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: -90%;
     left: 10%;
     fill: #e3e3e3;
     z-index: 0;
    }
```

```html
          <div id="centerContent">
            <nav id="mainNav">
       <a class="aqua" href="#">
        <span>aaa</span>
                    <svg></svg>
                </a><a
                    class="aqua" href="#">
        <span>bbb</span>
                    <svg></svg>
                </a><a
                    class="aqua" href="#">
        <span>ccc</span>
                    <svg></svg>
                </a><a
                    class="aqua" href="#">
        <span>ddd</span>
                    <svg></svg>
                </a>
           </nav>
        </div>
```

As you can see, the `#mainNav` width is `undefined` which makes its width as long as its children expand.

I want when I hover on each A tag, the mainNav stay in the center position to its container

Comment: well..it already does that ( changed with of container to 100%, maybe that's what's causing the issue. also added box-sizing:border-box) see here > https://jsfiddle.net/xzr3xm15/

Comment: well in your example you are right, but in my situation when I hover on elements the whole width of children go above 1020px which is the size of my container, I want even if the parent is smaller in width , my menu still stay in the center

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: well how would you want your nav to stay in center if it's width will be more than the container width ? go on a second row ?

Comment: well thats my question,I want to have a centered unknown width navigation which is still centered after changing its width, I approach this problem with inline-block display and text-align: center on the parent, but if you think there is a better approach for this problem please let me know

Comment: maybe i don't understand correctly. But my question is. Would you like an answer that will have the nav links that don't fit inside the container,go on the second line ?

Comment: nope I want to keep em in a same line

Comment: how do you expect them to 1. increase in width 2.their combined width more than the width of the container 3.stay on the same line ? :) only with overflow maybe

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper block with this styles:

```css
#centerContent {
    width: 700px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    }
        #mainNav {
        display: inline-block;
     height: 42px;
     background-color: #f5f5f5;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    #mainNav a {
     transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    #mainNav a > * {
     transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    #mainNav > a {
     display: inline-block;
     height: 100%;
     position: relative;
     font: 13px/42px "IranYekanWebLight";
     font-weight: 700;
     color: #575757;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #mainNav > a:hover {
     background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    #mainNav > a:hover span {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 17px;
     padding-right: 75px;
    }
    
    #mainNav > a:hover svg {
     left: 40%;
     fill: #fff;
     animation: 0.3s 1 mainNavAnim;
     animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    
    #mainNav span {
     padding: 0 28px;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
    }
    
    #mainNav svg {
     height: 90px;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: -90%;
     left: 10%;
     fill: #e3e3e3;
     z-index: 0;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="centerContent">
            <nav id="mainNav">
       <a class="aqua" href="#">
        <span>aaa</span>
                    <svg></svg>
                </a><a
                    class="aqua" href="#">
        <span>bbb</span>
                    <svg></svg>
                </a><a
                    class="aqua" href="#">
        <span>ccc</span>
                    <svg></svg>
                </a><a
                    class="aqua" href="#">
        <span>ddd</span>
                    <svg></svg>
                </a>
           </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: how exactly  ??,